# How to plot ListDensityPlot3D with four column data?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want a density plot with three-dimensional data of a function f[x,y,z]. The data is comprised of four columns corresponding to x,y,z,f. I tried using the following commands.

```
l = Import["data.dat","Data"];
ListDensityPlot3D[l, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

But it did not work. Can anyone kindly help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the example of `data.dat`

Comment: The data file which I tried to plot, can be found from the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUfNkw-lmS-eQZvWWSHUzZlgmikakw2U/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Not the the first coordinate of your data is a constant of: -9.04779

Comment: It is a variable. So it is changing.

Answer (score 1):

Removed as not valuable. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx